# R: summarize a large dataframe by multiple columns but don't summarize rows that in all the columns defined to summarize by the value is NA

Tags: r, dplyr, na, summarize

I would like to summarize a large dataframe by multiple columns, but, some of the rows in the dataframe contain only NAs in the columns I wish to summarise by, even though they are in fact different observations. I would like to keep all of the rows containing all NA values.

An example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
b = c(2,NA,2,1,NA,4),
c = c(1,2,1,NA,NA,1),
d = c(2,3,2,NA,NA,2),
e = c(3,2,NA,NA,NA,NA),
f = c(4,1,3,NA,NA,3))
```

I would like to summarize by columns c,d,e and f, and the desired output:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5),
b = c(2,NA,2,1,NA),
c = c(1,2,1,NA,NA),
d = c(2,3,2,NA,NA),
e = c(3,2,NA,NA,NA),
f = c(4,1,3,NA,NA))
```

tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dplyr, use the cumulative count of rows where all columns are `NA` as an additional grouping variable:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    all_na = if_all(c:f, is.na),
    all_na_grp = ifelse(all_na, cumsum(all_na), 0)
  ) %>%
  group_by(c, d, e, f, all_na_grp) %>%
  summarize(across(a:b, first), .groups = "drop") %>%
  select(a, b, !all_na_grp)
```

```
# A tibble: 5 × 6
      a     b     c     d     e     f
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     1     2     3     4
2     3     2     1     2    NA     3
3     2    NA     2     3     2     1
4     4     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
5     5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```